# Xaml data binding not refreshing

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, data-binding, maui

I am wondering how best to make the UI update when data changes.

I am working in a Maui app. I have this property in my VM:

```
[ObservableProperty]
public ObservableCollection<MyContentDTO> _contentFeed = new();
```

The DTO is something like this:

```
public class MyContentDTO
{
  public int MyNumber { get; set; }
}
```

In the UI I have this data bound:

```
<Label Text="{Binding MyNumber}" />
```

When I load, the data all appears as expected. At some point in the code I update MyNumber for the selected item but the UI doesn't update. I assume this is because it's not an ObservableProperty.

Do I need to change every property the UI is bound to so that they are ObservableProperties? If so this is a pain as I need to have a matching class for all my DTO's. I was hoping to just have the DTO's going straight to the UI.

Thanks

Comment: You have to use "INotifyPropertyChanged".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you used the [ObservableProperty]. Did you used the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm package? If so you can make class MyContentDTO inherit from the ObservableObject. Such as:

```
public partial class MyContentDTO : ObservableObject 
{
 [ObservableProperty]
  public int myNumber; 
}
```

The [ObservableProperty] will declare the `myNumber` as `MyNumber`. So you can still use `<Label Text="{Binding MyNumber}" />`.

Comment: Thanks - that works. And kind of seems obvious now you point it out!